# How to use one array in two functions in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have an array with the following content:

```
 $array_test = array ("User1"=>"Test1",
                      "User2"=>"Test2");
```

First column shall be $uservalue and second $testvalue in the functions. It worked, when I use a single column array for the first function loop through the array in the function.

And I would like to use this array in the following two functions.
The first column of the array should be use as $uservalue.

```
function do_show(array $options) {
    global $showresult, $master;
    $cn = $uservalue;
    $config = $options["config"]->value;
    // an empty show tag
    $show = new SimpleXMLElement("<show/>");
    // add the user tag
    $user = $show->addChild("user");
    // add the "cn" attribute
    $user->addAttribute("cn", $cn);
    if ($config)
        $user->addAttribute("config", "true");

    print "cmd: " . htmlspecialchars($show->asXML()) . "\n";

    // do it
    $showresult = $masterPBX->Admin($show->asXML());
    print "result: " . htmlspecialchars($showresult) . "\n";
    }
```

Second function where I would like to use the second Column of the array as Value for $testvalue:

```
function do_modify(array $options) {
    global $showresult, $master;
    $mod = $testvalue;
    $modify = new SimpleXMLElement("$showresult");
    $user = $modify->user;
    $path = explode("/device/hw/", $mod);
    $srch = $user;
    $nsegments = count($path);
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($path as $p) {
        if ($i == $nsegments) {
            // last part, the modification
            list($attr, $value) = explode("=", $p);
            $srch[$attr] = $value;
        } else {
            $srch = $srch->$p;
        }
        $i++;
    }

    // wrap the modified user tag in to a <modify> tag
    $modify = new SimpleXMLElement("<modify>" . $user->asXML() . "</modify>");
    print "cmd: " . htmlspecialchars($cmd = $modify->asXML()) . "\n";
    $result = $master->Admin($cmd);
    print "result: " . htmlspecialchars($result);
}
```

How can I archieve this? I found these two functions in the wiki of the software I would like to implement this... Therefore I know that using global variables is not a good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your array into two arrays using following code and pass appropriate array to relevant function.

```
$array_test = array ("User1"=>"Test1",
                      "User2"=>"Test2");
$array_users = array_keys($array_test);
$array_tests = array_values($array_test);
```

Here is the link for details on both [array_values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) and [array_keys](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) functions.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the array as a function parameter to both functions...or make the array global. Pass by reference if you want to change original array (your array changes made inside the function to be visible outside of the function).

Comment: Does this work, when it is necessary that the values of the array belong to each other? So, User1 does always need Test1 as value and User2 always Test2.